# Xamarin Forms Binding two properties from a single control to different contexts

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

I'm writing a Xamarin Forms app and I'm binding various properties of my XAML controls to a common class structure shared by all my pages.  In order to inform my code what controls are currently displayed on the top page,  I trigger an event and in the handler I determine if that control is visible.
I want to trigger the event with a local variable not part of the class structure.

```
<mr:Image ClassId="3" Source="{Binding ImagesDictionary[AudioOnOff],Converter={StaticResource imageFileToImageSourceConverter}}" 
   PropertyChanged="Image_PropertyChanged" 
   Opacity="{Binding CtrlTrigger}" 
   Down="Control_Image_Tapped" 
   InputTransparent="{Binding InhibitTouch}"  />
```

c#

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
   public double CtrlTrigger; // I'll connect this to a notify event, understood.

   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        BindingContext = MainPage.CabinData;
    }
}
```

How would I bind the Opacity property only to the CtrlTrigger double in my HomePage while allowing the other properties of the Image to be binded to the MainPage.CabinData class as set by the Binding context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XAML, at the top with the xmlns statements, give your page a name like `x:Name="MyAwesomePage"`. Then you can reference it in the Opacity Property:

```
Opacity="{Binding CtrlTrigger, Source={x:Reference MyAwesomePage}}"
```